# Не могу получить локацию

Tags: android, kotlin

Не хочет выводить координаты, в чем может быть проблема ?

```kotlin
class MyProfile : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var ttextVie: TextView

    private lateinit var locationManager: LocationManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile)


        ttextVie = findViewById(R.id.textView)

        locationManager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager


    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ttextVie.text = "нет разрешений"
            return
        } else {
            locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1L,
                1f,
                locationListener
            )

        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)
    }

    private val locationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            ttextVie.text = ("" + location.longitude + ":" + location.latitude)
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
    }
}
```

---

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Разрешения на местоположения в настройках включил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

У себя в проекте я использую такой способ:

```
private var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
private var mLocationRequest: LocationRequest? = null

private fun checkSelfLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            val permissions = arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 0)
        } else {

            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
            mLocationRequest?.interval = 10000
            mLocationRequest?.fastestInterval = 3000
            mLocationRequest?.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

            mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper())

        }
    }


    private var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
                val locIndex = locationResult.locations.size - 1
                val lon = locationResult.locations[locIndex].longitude
                val lat = locationResult.locations[locIndex].latitude


                if (!sp.contains("last_location") || sp.getString(
                        "last_lon",
                        ""
                    ) != "$lon" || sp.getString(
                        "last_lat",
                        ""
                    ) != "$lat"
                ) {

                    sp.edit().putString("last_lon", "$lon").apply()
                    sp.edit().putString("last_lat", "$lat").apply()

                    init(lat, lon)
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

и дальше остановка обновления местоположения делается так:

```
 mFusedLocationClient?.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
```

как можно понять из кода, это:

```
val lon = locationResult.locations[locIndex].longitude
val lat = locationResult.locations[locIndex].latitude
```

ваша локаль которую можно дальше использовать где вам нужно.